# How add php echo into html

Tags: php, html, database

I have created a random string generator and I want to register it in database so it needs POST or GET Method to send it to another file that regist it in database so, I use this code in HTML

```
   <form action="reg.php" method="POST"> 
    <button type="submit">Regist</button>
   </form>
```

and in echo its

```
 echo linsr();
```

I want to include the echo in POST Method in HTML to send it to reg.php!

how can I do this?

I know that I can do it in the same file but I want to send it in POST
method

so its possible to do that? not HTML in echo its echo in HTML

or can I make it directly? from PHP to PHP and no need to HTML

Comment: What's `linsr` is it a PHP function or a javascript function?

Comment: This question is not only too broad, it's unclear.

Comment: wait i will add all php code

Answer (score 3):

To include data in the POST request, add it as a field to your form. Type hidden would work well here:

```
<form action="reg.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="somename" value="<?php echo linsr(); ?>"/>
</form>
```

Comment: No name on the input?

Comment: i try it before! the database get null

Comment: Use `$_POST['somename']` to access the value of your field.